# Weight paint not showing on some objects

Tags: objects

I can select the head mesh and weight paint without problems. Other objects the rig controls like shirt are not showing in weight paint - they are staying grey. In weight paint face masking they are showing as Green. In vertex select they can be seen and changed. In weight paint vertex mask no vertex is visible and only the Green surface is shown.

[image]

I can manipulate and modify the weights of the other objects but only the Head is shown in weight paint mode. I hope this is something silly I am overlooking because it has left me very confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure without the blend file, but that can be due to the nature of the selected bones when you go in weight paint mode. Have you tried to select the bone group directly in the mesh data part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Subsurf modifier I had "Use OpenSubdiv" ticked & unclicking the box was enough to return the functionality. It sounds simple now but was by no means obvious!

Hope this saves someone else from going crazy...